# Comparing NDVI values inside polygons

Tags: python, polygon, raster, arcgis

I generated three NDVI images from Landsat5 imagery. Now I would like to see if the NDVI values (mean) are different inside three different areas in each image. If you check the image in the link you can see two polygons (red and blue). I would like to use the shapefile with the polygons and extract the the mean NDVI values (from the raster) inside read, blue, and the mean values outside the two polygons.
[Image with polygons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CySc.png)

I have no idea what tools to use to get the NDVI values from inside and just inside the polygons.
I think I would need a third polygon  for the "outside" values, however It would have to exclude the red and blue values.

In the end I want to do this programmatically using Python, however I need to know what steps to take and what tools to use.

Answer (score 1):

You do not provide the type of file with NDVI data. Imagine it is `.tif` file.

Rasterio and fiona should do all the staff:

```
import rasterio
import fiona
import rasterio.mask
import numpy as np

# Load boundary
with fiona.open(path_to_shapefile, "r") as sf:
    shapes = [feature["geometry"] for feature in sf]

# Crop the tif
with rasterio.open(source_tif) as src:
    out_image, out_transform = rasterio.mask.mask(src, shapes, crop=True)

# Calculate mean value
NDVI_mean = np.mean(out_image)
```

Also [rasterio mask](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.mask.html) allows to choose pixels outside the polygon by setting `invert=True`